# How to make a php page redirect to an error page with certain conditions

Tags: php

Basically, When a user signs up (**register.php**) succesfully..
I store all the data in database and direct them to **step.php** using

```
header("location: step.php");
```

Where they fill **other** different info which is then stored in the database.

So, a user must access the **register.php** page before accessing the **step.php** page.

How do I stop access to the **step.php** page by limiting its access to only those that just completed the **register.php** form.

PS - I am building a step by step registration process and is this even the best way out. Or what other ways can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: can u please show more code

Comment: I know how to make redirect @WilliamPerron. But certain condition has to be met before making the redirect.

Comment: @Ibrahim knowing what `step.php` actually does might be useful to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-start.php), set a session if the user did gone through register php (set it bevor you redirect the user).
If step.php is called, check for that session.

```
<?
//register.php Line 1
session_start();

//At the End
$_SESSION['doneRegister'] = true;
header("location: step.php");
?>
```

```
<?
//step.php Line 1
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['doneRegister'])){
// Session not set
header("location: register.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: A simple example of some boiler plate code would change this from a fairly unhelpful comment into an answer

Comment: It's also fairly obvious from the question that OP *is already* using sessions

Answer (score 0):

On register page: `define('VAR', true);`
On top of step page: `if (!defined('VAR')) header('location:index.php');`